# Definite integral of a bounded function on a bounded interval depends at least linearly on integration extremes?

Tags: definite-integrals

I think that the title of the thread summarises all I would like to know about an integral of one variable only. The question may appear silly (maybe it actually is), but it stems from the idea of the raw approximation of an integral provided by calculating the area of a rectangle over the domain of integration.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please clarify your question. What do you mean by “depends at least linearly”?

Comment: Hi thanks. I think that it is better-off to tell the whole story. I need to deal with some definite integrals and the only thing I know is that the integrand function, say $f$, is bounded over the integration interval, which is of the form $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ and $\epsilon=O(n^{-1/2})$, where $n$ is a quantity that potentially grows to infinity. The goal is to say that the integral is just $O(n^{-1/2})$, not interested on its actual value at all. (continued below)

Comment: Because I have not much information to try to figure out how the integral would look like, I will be just happy to say that "always" the integral can be thought as a linear function of integration extremes. In writing the reply, I came out with the following argument: $\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x) d(x)=g(\epsilon)-g(-\epsilon)$. Taylor expanding $g$ about $0$ gives $g(0)-g(0)+\epsilon g'(0) -\epsilon g'(0) + O(\epsilon^2)=O(\epsilon)$, as long as $g'(0)$ and $g''(0)$ are bounded. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to answer your question: Let $f:[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be bounded by a constant $C>0$ and integrable. Then
$$|\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon f(t)\, dt|\leq \int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon |f(t)|\, dt \leq C\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}dt=2C\varepsilon$$
hence the integral is in $O(\varepsilon)$.